# django migration error on changing FK field to regular field

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Part of my model looked like this, initially. I'm using PostgreSQL.

```
class RealTimeLocation(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    latlng = models.PointField(default=None)


class CabLog(models.Model):

    location = models.ForeignKey(RealTimeLocation,
                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                      related_name='cablog_locations')
```

Then i thought, no need for an FK field, so i changed the fk field to a Point field.

```
class RealTimeLocation(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    latlng = models.PointField(default=None)


class CabLog(models.Model):

    location = models.PointField()//
```

'python manage.py makemigrations ' no issues, but on migrate i'm getting error.

> .django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "location_id" of relation "myapp_cablog" does not exist.

I tried adding a null=True option to pointfield, deleting the migrate-scripts and redo it many times, no avail. SO before i completely fake-migrate the entire project and startover, do anybody have any solutions for this. I already got some data in DB, so i really don't want to do that. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to access `location_id` somewhere in your code (the _complete_ error traceback probably even gives you a hint where)...

Comment: the 'location_id' is from the postgres column. All FK fiels are stores in DB as it's 'fieldname_id'. I tried to make it in DB using PgAdmin. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you run only `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
You must run `sqlmigrate` also.

Try these three commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #You didn't run this command after makemigrations that's why you got that error

python manage.py migrate
```

**Note**: 0001 this value will generate after makemigrations. It can be either 0001, 0002 and so on.

Comment: Yea, this will delete my entire data, and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: only that FK field will delete

Comment: Yea data won't be deleted, my bad.

Comment: Not working. still getting the error after step 3..django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "location_id" of relation "myapp_cablog" does not exist.

Comment: which value you used while doing sqlmigrate

Comment: i used 0001_initial, i even used it in the last step.

Comment: You must use only that value when you do makemigrations appname. That value will generate after makemigrations

Comment: i did that too.. the migration successful. but whenever accessing the data, error message.

Comment: Means you didn't get any error while migrations

Comment: Yea, dude, i fixed the bug. I went to the postgresDB table using pgadmin. Created a new column named 'location' of type geometry(Point,4326). Thanks for time and efforts anyway. appreciate it.

Comment: Great ok fine happy coding

Comment: I probably accidentally deleted many of my intermediate migration scripts,earlier, which could cause the issue. lesson learned- i read somewhere initial migration docs-  "Django compares changes against the migration files, not the database. Django won't be able to detect that the DB doesn't match your models".

Comment: Do migrations again for those migrations file which deleted

Comment: I think the slate is clean now. So deleting all other scripts in migration file other than initial, now would be okay . The deletion order matters too i guess. Anyway django migration is an unreliable tool fr.

Comment: @ISONecroMAn Django migrations are very reliable, although the moment you begin deleting / editing migration files (or using flags like `--fake`) without understanding what you're doing that statement doesn't stand anymore.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat. Sorry, have to disagree with that. Django Migrations are super unreliable. It had caused me enormous headaches in the last few years on various problems. I had to mirror backup data on multiple occasions. Not only my experience, but a lot of people i know share the same opinion. When using migrations, always do it in small steps, and always check on every check. Super Unreliable piece of ****.